i get the "unexpected token ..." when trying to run npx create-next-app
I recently got into arch, I believe I've got everything that i need already installed. But for some reason when trying to run npx create-next-app "name" i get the following error in the console.
enter image description here
does anyone have any idea why this might be happening.
I tried some solutions that other ppl gave to a similar issue but it didn't seem to have worked.

What node version are you using? node --version
As per Next.js docs:

You’ll need Node.js version 18 or higher.


I just updated it to v20.11.0 i believe that's ok too :(

Have you tried specifying a Next version?
npx create-next-app@latest

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
